# lambda expressions

Tags: java, lambda

недавно изучаю лямбды.

Вот вопрос:
у меня есть работающий код лямбды:

```java
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CompareAble test = (s1, s2) -> {
            if(s1.length() >= s2.length()) return s1;
            else return s2;
        };

        System.out.println(test.compare("1", "12"));
    }
}


interface CompareAble{
    String compare(String s1, String s2);
}
```

Тоесть я создаю ссылку CompareAble-а

можно ли (не знаю зачем, просто интересует возможность реализации) организовать реализацию этой лямбды типа вот так:

```java
public class Test implements CompareAble{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        System.out.println(test.compare("1", "12"));
    }

    (s1, s2) -> {
        if(s1.length() >= s2.length()) return s1;
        else return s2;
    };


}


interface CompareAble{
    String compare(String s1, String s2);
}
```

Comment: Может вопрос глупый, но всё же прошу ответить без агрессии

Comment: Непонятно , что именно имеется в виду под "типа вот так". Какая у вас цель во второй реализации? Лямбда выражение позволяет передавать поведение. В приведенном примере поведение никуда не передается. У переменной экземпляра класса тест вы вызываете метод интерфейса, который этот класс имплементирует. Достаточно переопределить метод и все будет работать.

Comment: "Позволяет передавать поведение" - мне это помогло понять насколько всё же глупый мой вопрос, спасибо за отклик!

Comment: Не за что)) Удачи в изучении Java. А еще вместо if-else в методе compare попробуйте тернарник : return s1.length() >= s2.length() ? s1 : s2; так на много меньше кода